# Xcode crashes when I delete app from iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

I'm not doing anything special, but my Xcode becomes buggy if I delete the app from iPhone and I usually have to restart Xcode.

This doesn't happen all the time, but happens very frequently. I'm using Xcode 8.2.1

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: As debug, I assume that it will act as the app crashes, without any problem to the Xcode itself

Comment: Is Xcode itself actually crashing here? Or do you actually mean your app appears to crash in the debugger? There's a huge difference and you should update your title and question to be more clear.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm not sure what I need to change. Xcode crashes. I never said app crashes.

Comment: OK, I was just trying to clarify. It's odd that Xcode itself actually crashes. What version of Xcode?

Comment: @rmaddy I made an edit. Still working on Swift 2.3  with Xcode 8.2.1 :(

Comment: Any crash log from Xcode? This is not usual.

Comment: @Ryan Actually I wrote it bad. It doesn't crash. It just hangs or does nothing when I run the project again. If I want to quit Xcode I can't. I only have to force quit it.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was **stop** the app from Xcode **before** I delete the app from device.